Update package.json with jq
I am working on a web application that utilizes in-house npm packages.
These packages have names that begin with the prefix @glen/
The assignment is parse and to modify the package.json file by removing the -dev.3 and -rc.0 tags specifically for the @glen/ prefix.
Example:
"@glen/manager": "^3.0.0-rc.0", -> "@glen/manager": "^3.0.0",
I expect to use jq, but any other suggestion running on Linux is welcome!
Original package.json:
    {
      "name": "@glen/web_trans",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "nuxt build",
        "dev": "nuxt dev",
        "generate": "nuxt generate",
        "prepare": "husky install"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@glen/manager": "^3.0.0-rc.0",
        "@glen/handler": "^1.3.6",
        "@glen/extension": "^3.3.0-dev.3",
        "@nuxt/devtools": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
        "@nuxtjs/device": "^3.1.1",
        "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^8.0.0-rc.5",
        "eslint": "^8.29.0",
        "husky": "^8.0.0",
        "jsdom": "^21.1.1",
        "nuxt": "3.7.4",
        "vitest": "^0.29.7"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@glen/manager": "^3.0.0-rc.0",
        "@glen/handler": "^1.3.6",
        "@glen/extension": "^3.3.0-dev.3",
        "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.6",
        "@vee-validate/rules": "^4.11.3",
        "@vue/apollo-composable": "^4.0.0-beta.1",
        "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.2",
        "@vueuse/components": "^9.6.0",
        "@vueuse/core": "^9.6.0",
        "websocket": "^1.0.34"
      },
      "extensionPack": [
        "Vue.volar"
      ],
      "overrides": {
        "vue": "latest"
      }
    }

After update he must look like:
    {
      "name": "@glen/web_trans",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "nuxt build",
        "dev": "nuxt dev",
        "generate": "nuxt generate",
        "prepare": "husky install"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@glen/manager": "^3.0.0",
        "@glen/handler": "^1.3.6",
        "@glen/extension": "^3.3.0",
        "@nuxt/devtools": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
        "@nuxtjs/device": "^3.1.1",
        "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^8.0.0-rc.5",
        "eslint": "^8.29.0",
        "husky": "^8.0.0",
        "jsdom": "^21.1.1",
        "nuxt": "3.7.4",
        "vitest": "^0.29.7"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@glen/manager": "^3.0.0",
        "@glen/handler": "^1.3.6",
        "@glen/extension": "^3.3.0",
        "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.6",
        "@vee-validate/rules": "^4.11.3",
        "@vue/apollo-composable": "^4.0.0-beta.1",
        "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.2",
        "@vueuse/components": "^9.6.0",
        "@vueuse/core": "^9.6.0",
        "websocket": "^1.0.34"
      },
      "extensionPack": [
        "Vue.volar"
      ],
      "overrides": {
        "vue": "latest"
      }
    }


How about using NPM? Or show your attempts using jq please.

It's expect to be like a verification to no permit to use -dev or -rc into prod

jq '(.dependencies,.devDependencies) |=
        with_entries(.value = if .key | startswith("@glen/")
                              then  .value | split("-")[0]
                              else .value
                              end)
   ' file.json


It is functioning flawlessly!
